# Rails 4 - Twitter Typeahead Not Working

Tags: java, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-typeahead

I'm a beginner in Ruby on rails and trying to implement twitter typeahead in rails 4. This code working fine on an empty project but not in my existing project.

application.js

```
//= require jquery.min
//= require typeahead.min
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery.dataTables.min.js
//= require dataTables.bootstrap.js
//= require_tree .
```

GemFile

```
gem 'twitter-typeahead-rails'
```

custom.js // ERROR was here, previous name was typeahead-custum.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#input').typeahead({
      name: 'ports',
      prefetch: '/ports.json',
      limit: 5
    });

});
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= search_field_tag :lp, nil, class: "form-control", id: "input", placeholder: 'From: ' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer. My custom javascript's name was typeahead-custom.js. I renamed it to custom.js and it is working fine now.